# How to reset a bulleted list to normal text and back in QTextEdit

Tags: python, qtextedit, pyqt6

I am trying to set the selected lines to bullet points and back, here i set the indent to 0, it destroys the bullet points, yet the list property remains true, so this code will not set the same line back to bullet list again, how to clear the underlying list format, Or what is the best approach?

```
    def bullet_list(self):
    cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
    list = cursor.currentList()
    if list:
        listfmt = cursor.currentList().format()
        listfmt.setIndent(0)
        cursor.createList(listfmt)
        self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.textEdit.setFocus()

    else:
        listFormat = QTextListFormat()
        style = QTextListFormat.Style.ListDisc
        listFormat.setStyle(style)
        cursor.createList(listFormat)
        self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.textEdit.setFocus()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items must be removed from the list, and you should also not use `createList` again.

```
    def bullet_list(self):
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        textList = cursor.currentList()
        if textList:
            start = cursor.selectionStart()
            end = cursor.selectionEnd()
            removed = 0
            for i in range(textList.count()):
                item = textList.item(i - removed)
                if (item.position() <= end and
                    item.position() + item.length() > start):
                        textList.remove(item)
                        blockCursor = QTextCursor(item)
                        blockFormat = blockCursor.blockFormat()
                        blockFormat.setIndent(0)
                        blockCursor.mergeBlockFormat(blockFormat)
                        removed += 1
            self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
            self.textEdit.setFocus()
        else:
            listFormat = QTextListFormat()
            style = QTextListFormat.ListDisc
            listFormat.setStyle(style)
            cursor.createList(listFormat)
            self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
            self.textEdit.setFocus()
```

<sup>Note: `list` is a Python builtin, assigning it to anything else is considered bad practice.</sup>

Comment: @JackZero Note that I've updated the answer, so that only list items that are in the selection gets removed.